# Creating unique values for data table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, uniqueidentifier

I have a P&L (profit & loss) data dump where there are multiple instances of the same description that I need to make unique. There are 18 business units and about 10-11 departments that are not numerically sequenced within each business unit.

For example: Each of the 10-11 depts (e.g. "Produce") are listed 3 times for each business unit, once under the Sales, Gross Profit and Salaries headers, all in the same column.

I want to concatenate the respective header with the department (e.g. "SALES-Produce", "GROSS PROFIT-Produce", "SALARIES-Produce").

Sorry, I wanted to attached an example, but I need at least 10 reputation, which I apparently don't have.

EDIT to include information (from comments):

I want to create a data table in Excel and use Pivot Tables. The data dump is basically a `csv` file that looks like the hard copy report. For example:

Column A has the P&L line description, some of which is not unique, Column B has 2013 actual $ amounts, Column C has 2014 Budget $ amounts, Column D has 2014 actual $ amounts

Currently:

```
"SALES"
"Produce"
"Meat"
<other department names>

"SALES"

"GROSS PROFIT"
"Produce"
"Meat"
etc.

"GROSS PROFIT"

"SALARIES"
"Produce"
"Meat"
etc.

"SALARIES"
```

desired results:

```
"SALES - Produce"
"SALES - Meat"
etc.

"GROSS PROFIT - Produce"
"GROSS PROFIT - Meat"
etc.

"SALARIES - Produce"
"SALARIES - Meat"
etc.
```

Comment: Can you put some of your existing code into the question?

Comment: How do I put my existing code into the question?

Comment: You can [copy and paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Copy_and_paste) it from your source into the question.

Comment: I don't follow. I have an example of the data dump, in .xlsx file or I could make it into a PDF. How do attach it or share it with my question? Sorry, I'm new to this site and how it works.

Comment: So what you're saying is you haven't tried anything yourself yet? Can you give examples of what you have and what you're trying to achieve, and maybe tell us what language you'd like to try to use in order to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry. This is all in Excel. I want to create a data table in Excel and use Pivot Tables. The data dump is basically a csv file that looks like the hard copy report. For example: Column A has the P&L line description, some of which is not unique, Column B has 2013 actual $ amounts, Column C has 2014 Budget $ amounts, Column D has 2014 actual $ amounts

Comment: Column A data: row 1 = "SALES", row 2-11 = different depts, like "Produce" & "Meat", row 12 = blank, row 13 = "  SALES", representing the total. Subsequent rows is the same, but for headers like "GROSS PROFIT", "SALARIES"

Comment: I want to make each P&L line item description unique, specifically the department names by adding the P&L header. So for example, for the 10 depts (rows 2-11) under "SALES" (row = 1), I want to make it "SALES-Dept Name" (e.g. SALES-Produce"). The same logic for the same departments under different P&L headers (e.g. "GROSS PROFIT" & "SALARIES")